# Find element in list that contains unicodes

Tags: python, list, unicode, find

I have below list, and I would like to know if element "caston" is part of the list.

```
a = [{u'us': u'Running', u'HalfTima': u'1234', u'Boks': u'caston', u'KickoffTime': 1507401900000L, u'AwayName': u'jose'}]
```

I have tried below foudcodes but it does not work since I always get False instead of True:

```
print type(a)

print ("'caston'" in a)

print ( "u'caston'" in a)

print (caston in a)

print ("caston" in a)
```

Could you please advise what is the correct way to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: You have a dict inside of the list, so what you are actually looking for a value in a dict.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
a = [{u'us': u'Running', u'HalfTima': u'1234', u'Boks': u'caston', u'KickoffTime': 1507401900000L, u'AwayName': u'jose'}]
print("caston" in a[0].values())
```

Output:

```
True
```

Answer (score -1):

Using `str` function `list` can be converted into string and then you can search for the required string.

e.g.

```
>>> a = [{u'us': u'Running', u'HalfTima': u'1234', u'Boks': u'caston', u'KickoffTime': 1507401900000L, u'AwayName': u'jose'}]
>>> 'caston' in str(a)
True
>>>
```

Answer (score -1):

if you `only` want to check if  element "caston" is part of the list then you can check using regex :

```
import re
a=r"[{u'us': u'Running', u'HalfTima': u'1234', u'Boks': u'caston', u'KickoffTime': 1507401900000L, u'AwayName': u'jose'}]"

pattern=r'\bcaston\b'

match=re.search(pattern,a)
if match:
    print(True)
```